# SwiftUI tapGesture not accurately counting

Tags: swiftui, uigesturerecognizer

This simple code snippet recognizes a single tap gesture, and a triple tap gesture, but not a double tap gesture. Any idea why?

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Image(systemName: "globe")
            .imageScale(.large)
            .onTapGesture(count: 3) {
                print ("tap thrice 3")
            }
            .onTapGesture(count: 2) {
                print ("tap twice 2")
            }
            .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                print ("tap once 1")
            }
    }
}
```